# How to obtain the center of mass energy needed to form a black hole in a particle accelerator?

Tags: energy, black-holes, estimation, large-hadron-collider

Once, Hawking has brushed aside the worries about LHC forming black holes massive enough to actually cause damage.

I want to know which estimate he has used. After all, it is not possible to asign a size in the sense of general relativity to a object such as a proton. (Do not come with form factors.)

So quantum gravity speculations aside, how would one estimate the energy needed to form a black hole in, say, proton proton collision?

EDIT: To clarify: I do not care about the life time of bh. Tell me the physical principle that is needed to estimate the **energy needed to form a bh** . As an analogy: The determination of the anomalous magnetic factor relies on the principle of qft and using perturbation theory and one can calculate the quantum corrections. Its exact values will be model dependent though.

The Hubble constant can be inferred from the CMB power spectrum by (simplified) calculating the distance of last scattering and looking at the sound horizon. The exact value is model dependent.

In the same way, there should be an estimate to get the minimal needed COM energy to form a BH from pp collision.

El psy kongroo.

Comment: More on [black holes at LHC](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-holes+large-hadron-collider).

Comment: Sorry, but the answers and questions are popular science at best, make belief at worst. I do not want to assume that: 1) a black hole forms 2) some macroscopic analogy. I want to know the physical arguments people USE to get to the conclusion: At cern (about 14TeV) we "may" (or may not) create BH of a certain mass given some initial COM energy.

Comment: *it is not possible to asign a size in the sense of general relativity to a object such as a proton* What is your source for this strange claim?

Comment: This strange claim comes from the fact that in qunatum physics, a particle does not behave as a solid body. You can name a lot of radii for particles, but all of them come from form factors, which is interaction dependent. (and definetely not using gravity cross sections!) You can of course tell me your scheme of how to assign a radius to protons, electrons or similar. @Ghoster

Comment: You should fix your title to something descriptive of the question, not a reaction to the discussion. Yes, if you ask about LHC black holes on this site, you're going to have people lining up to tell you that the LHC can't destroy the world and it was so dumb that people thought that. Doesn't matter what you actually asked about. There are so many people ready to rehash this ancient discussion. I see the same thing with global warming related questions. Someone will ask a specific question about atmospheric physics and they'll get a gaggle of comments saying "global warming is real."

Comment: @AXensen Thank you, I will keep that in mind for another question. Honestly, I've grown fond of this passive aggressive title though. I think it also is catchy enough for people to at least have a closer look.

Comment: Ok, alright, someone changed it for me. That's fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some physical arguments ...

The particle energies at CERN give us an upper limit on the mass of any black holes that could possibly be created. And that in turn gives us an upper limit on the size of the event horizon for these hypothetical black holes. They would be microscopic.

The phenomena of [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) allows us to estimate the lifetime of such hypothetical microscopic black holes. It would be very short indeed.

Can we rule out the possibility that microscopic, short-lived black holes could be created at CERN ? No - in fact, serious searches for traces of such black holes have been made, as their discovery would likely involve exciting new physics, Nobel prizes etc.

If microscopic black holes were formed at CERN, would they cause significant damage ? No, because they are too small and too short-lived. And also because particle collisions more energetic than those at CERN occur frequently in the upper atmosphere due to cosmic rays, and we know those collisions are not dangerous. You probably wouldn't a microscopic black hole evaporating inside your body - but you wouldn't want to be close to the CERN particle beams anyway.

For more information see [this CERN FAQ](https://angelsanddemons.web.cern.ch/faq/black-hole.html).

Comment: this does not answer the question. I neither care about the life time, nor the "danger" involved. The website you linked suggests that there is no general estimate coming from "bottom up" (i.e. from known physics) and hence the answer would be model dependent. The physical principles that need to be invoked to reach such estimates would be the desired answer.

Comment: To comment on your answer: The life time estimate is not correct. Hawking radiation would be (unless by some miracle this is not the case) in general not applicable to a BH formed at TeV range, since the temperatures would be insanely large, going far beyond SM physics. But "most likely" the life time is still short, I (despite lacking any evidence) agree

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 The underlying physical principles are conservation of energy and the known physics of black holes. If by "model dependent" you mean that there is an assumption that our understanding of microscopic black holes is substantially correct, that is true - but if you are going to invoke some as-yet-undiscovered physics then you might as well ask "can CERN create pink fluffy unicorns ?".

Comment: Conservation of energy would answer the question: what is the upper bound on the mass of a black hole formed at pp collision. Im asking (in principle): Whats the "lower bound" (estimate) on the energy TO form a bh, and which physical principles are needed to get such a bound. The second part is the true question, I dont really need a number.

Comment: The exact value of the energy needed for pp collisions to form a bh is model dependent. However, any such estimate would need to invoke some physical principle. Clearly, there is a problem in saying that the "protons would need to be so energetic that they are inside their schwarzschild radius", since there is no such thing as a size for protons. But if this is not the principle of bh formation, what is?

Answer (score 1):

At CERN routine proton-proton collision energies are about 13Tev. In 2018 they switched to lead ion collisions. These collisions had an collision energy of about 5.36 Tev per nucleon pair and a lead ion has 208 nucleons. In practice not every nucleon in a lead ion collides with a corresponding nucleon in the other ion, but if we take the worst case and assume they do, then we could say the collision energy of the ions is about 1114 Tev. The highest energy extraterrestrial gamma particle ever detected, the so called [Oh-My-God particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle) had an energy of about 320,000,000 Tev. In short, gamma rays collide with atoms in our atmosphere at collision energies that are orders of magnitude higher than those produced at CERN. ***If we are concerned about potential black hole formation at CERN, we should be more concerned about the high energy particles that have been colliding with our atmosphere for millions of years.***

[Wikipedia gives the evaporation time of black hole due to Bekenstein/Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) as approximately $$t \approx 3.396 \times 10^{-16} \ \left(\frac{M}{kg}\right)^3 s$$

The rest mass of the two lead ions is $6.88 \times 10^{-25} kg$.

The collision energy of the lead ions is $\approx 1114 \text{TeV} \approx 1.8 \times 10^{-4} \text{joules}$.

The rest mass equivalent of the collision energy is  $$ \frac{(1.8×10^{-4} \text{ joules})}{(\text{speed of light})^2} \approx 2 \times 10^{-21} kg$$

If this mass equivalent is compressed into a small enough volume by the collision and forms a black hole, then the evaporation time would be $$t \approx 3.396 \times 10^{-16} \ \left(\frac{(6.88 \times 10^{-25} + 2 \times 10^{-21}) \ kg }{kg}\right)^3 s \approx 2.7 \times 10^{-78} s,$$ assuming the the micro black hole does not absorb matter or background radiation in that time. The Planck time interval is $\approx 5.4 \times 10^{−44} \ s \ $ so the micro black hole would evaporate in approximately $1/(10^{34})$ of a Planck time interval.

It is hypothetically possible that micro black holes are being produced nearly all the time in CERN collisions (assuming they are compressed into a small enough volume)  but evaporate almost immediately on a time scale that we cannot currently measure.

We currently do not know if there is a minimum mass requirement for a black hole. We only know there is a minimum density requirement.

Comment: In your reference to the OMG particle, you missed a critical aspect, which is often missed in these discussions debunking the LHC black hole concerns. The OMG particle did not hit another 50J particle head on. It hit a fixed target. This gives a center of mass energy of sqrt(2mE), where E=50J and $m\approx 1$GeV. The center of mass energy was only about 700 TeV, only 50 times the center of mass energy of LHC collisions, not 40 million times.

Comment: I've now realized that this is even discussed in the wiki for the OMG particle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle. Except that for $m$ they plug in the mass of a nitrogen atom, which is nonsense - when a proton collides with a nucleus at TeV scales, it is the quarks that collide, not the entire proton with the entire nucleus. So which atom the particle collided with is irrelevant, and they shouldn't have taken the factor of the number of nucleons in nitrogen.

Comment: It seems probable that the OMG particle is not the highest energy gamma ray to ever have hit the Earth in recent history or we were very very lucky. It seems very likely there have been higher energy particles and they have not hit the gamma ray detectors that represent a tiny fraction of the Earths surface. 50 times the  energy of the CERN collisions is still an order of magnitude greater than the CERN collisions.

Comment: It does not answer my question. Where does the claim "the smallest possible bh is of planck mass" come from? Why the planck mass? If this can be reasoned, I will accept that as an answer

Comment: I was using the Planck mass as a reference point because some people think different physics is required to describe interactions an Planckian scales of time and length. You might of noticed I did the calculations for a mass smaller than the Planck mass in the second half of the original answer. I have now removed any reference to Planck mass to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok, good. But still, the question does not concern itself with the life time etc. of potential bh. @KDP

Comment: The title of your question is "The worries about CERN and miniature black holes". My answer basically demonstrates that there is nothing to worry about. If your question is really about if it is theoretical possible to produce a black hole at CERN, then I would say it cannot be ruled out iff the compression is high enough, but there would be no danger.

Comment: @KDP I changed the title. Please focus more on the text below the title. I normally have the key questions at the end.